# How to add event listener to display textbox when button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, event-listener

I'm making an application to create survey questions. Basically, users add questions by typing in the question name and then adding a type of answer which can either be short answer or multiple choice.

Every time the Add MC answer button is pressed, I would like the webpage to display an extra text box where the user can type in their 'answer text'. A textbox should not be displayed when the user clicks the Add short answer button. This is what I've got so far. How do i fix my code? So far, nothing is happening when i click the add mc answer button and I have a input field for typing in an answer but I don't want this to be displayed unless the button has been clicked.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let num_answers = 0;
  document.getElementById("answer").addEventListener("click", function() {
    let elem = document.createElement("input");
    elem.name = "answer" + num_answers;
    document.getElementById("answer_input").appendChild(elem);
    num_answers++;
  });
});
```

```html
<h1> Survey System </h1>
<form method="POST">
  <input name="question" placeholder="Enter a question" /><br/>

  <button type="button" name="answer" value="Add MC answer">Add MC answer</button><br>
  <input name="answer_input" placeholder="Enter an answer" /><br/>
  <button type="button" name="answer" value="Add short answer">Add short answer</button><br>

  <input type="radio" name="required" value="Mandatory">Mandatory<br>
  <input type="radio" name="required" value="Optional">Optional<br>
  <button type="submit" name="submit_question" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `name` is not `id`. Also, `input` can't have HTML, you've to append the newly-created element to some other existing element.

Comment: You have no element with an identifier of `answer`, hence `document.getElementById("answer")` doesn't find an element to attach the click event to. Same for `getElementById("answer_input")` You can use `getElementsByName()` instead and then iterate through each element.

Comment: I changed the method to getElementsByName but it's still not working? Is there anything else wrong?

Comment: @M.Ng Either ad an identifier to use `getElementById` or you need to iterate through all matches found by `getelementsByName` Please see the documentation to understand how to use them [**getElementsByName**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) and [**getElementById**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Answer (score 1):

I changed the buttons to have individual ids.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let num_answers = 0;
  let mcAnswer = document.getElementById("mcAnswer");
  mcAnswer.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let elem = document.createElement("input");
    elem.name = "answer";
    //document.getElementById("answer_input").appendChild(elem);
    // inserts elem after mcAnswer
    mcAnswer.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, mcAnswer.nextSibling);
    num_answers++;
  });
});
```

```html
<h1> Survey System </h1>
<form method="POST">
  <input name="question" placeholder="Enter a question" /><br/>

  <button type="button" id="mcAnswer" value="Add MC answer">Add MC answer</button><br>
  <input name="answer_input" placeholder="Enter an answer" /><br/>
  <button type="button" id="shortAnswer" value="Add short answer">Add short answer</button><br>

  <input type="radio" name="required" value="Mandatory">Mandatory<br>
  <input type="radio" name="required" value="Optional">Optional<br>
  <button type="submit" name="submit_question" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hmm this doesn't seem to be working for me. Actually my bad, it's working

Comment: Hey, I was also wondering, if I wanted to get the items that were typed into the extra textboxes that were created, how would I refer to each input field that is created? Is it called input? But there are multiple inputs?

Comment: Each generated input has unique name attributes, so you can refer to them by their names. So in other words, you can do `document.getElementsByName("answer1")[0]` to get the first generated input. If you want to loop through the inputs, I suggest you add a class name for the generated inputs then loop through `document.getElementsByClassName("generatedInputs")`

Comment: My application is in Python, and I'm using Flask. How would I loop through the generated inputs to extract the things that were typed into the boxes so that I can use it in my code? I am not very familiar with class names.. I'm not sure if you are familiar with python but for example to get the question text, I can write q_name = request.form["question"] where  "question" is the name of the button. How do I actually see the physical names so that I can use it in my Python code? Thanks for your help so far, and sorry for all the questions but I"m still confused

Comment: In this case, what you can do is have the generated inputs to have the same name attribute and I think you can do `request.form.getlist('answer')` to get multiple values from inputs of `name="answer"`. I have updated my answer, basically making all the generated inputs name to be "answer" `elem.name = "answer"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
    <html>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
                let num_answers = 0;
                //Edit done here - changed to correct ID Name
                document.getElementById("answerMC").addEventListener("click", function () {
                    //Edit done here - added hidden attribute change on the input
                    document.getElementById("answerInput").hidden = false;
                    let elem = document.createElement("input");
                    elem.name = "answer" + num_answers;
                   document.getElementById("answer_input").appendChild(elem);
                    num_answers++;
                });
           });
       </script>
       <body>
           <h1> Survey System </h1>
           <form method="POST">
               <input name="question" placeholder="Enter a question"/><br/>

               <!-- Edit done here - added id to the button -->
               <button type="button" name="answer" id="answerMC" value="Add MC answer">Add MC answer</button><br>
               <!-- Edit done here - added id to the button -->
               <input name="answer_input" id="answerInput" placeholder="Enter an answer" hidden/><br/>
               <button type="button" name="answer" value="Add short answer">Add short answer</button><br>

               <input type="radio" name="required" value="Mandatory">Mandatory<br>
               <input type="radio" name="required" value="Optional">Optional<br>
               <button type="submit" name="submit_question" value="Submit">Submit</button>
           </form>
      </body>
   </html>
```

Add 'ids' to your elements then add event listeners and you can use 'hidden' attribute to hide and show elements when needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using a bit of css styling, then you can create a custom class with the style property `display:none` also, you can add classes with the same class name for the text box and write a click event function,

```
document.getElementById("id of add short answer").addeventlistener("click",function(){document.getElementByClassName("class name of text boxes").addClass("class name given in styling");});
```

This will solve your issue.Also make sure you add ID's so that you are able to use `getElementById` method.